# How do I test rescue_from for routing failures?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In our rails 2.3 app, I've set up a rescue_from for routing errors as follows:

```
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError,       :with => :redirect_or_render_error
rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController,  :with => :redirect_or_render_error
rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction,      :with => :redirect_or_render_error
```

and then in my `redirect_or_render_error` method I redirect certain URLs (pulled from the DB, so I can't just use routes.rb) and I'd like to test this.  I'm doing it in the functional test for my index page (is that the right place?) as so:

```
@request.remote_addr = '12.34.56.78' # fake remote request
get '/example'
assert_redirected_to '/example_things/123456'
```

I get

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:action=>"/example", :controller=>"home"}
```

even though it works in development.  How do I test rescue_from for routing failures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I have to use an integration test rather than a functional test, like so:

```
get '/example', {}, :remote_addr => '12.34.56.78'
assert_redirected_to '/example_things/123456'
```

and I also needed to set `config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local` to false in config/environments/test.rb

Comment: Using an integration test resolves the issue as described here. However, I left `config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local` set to `true` in the test environment file.

Answer (score 0):

You are asserting something is true about your routes. That's not the case. You have a set of routes you plan not to map and you're going to handle that in an exception handler. (Aside: I think you should try to handle as many cases as possible in your routes.rb and let a normal Ruby method take care of any further action.)

In any case, to really test this, you want to do more along the lines of:

```
@request.remote_addr = '12.34.56.78' # fake remote request
assert_raise ActionController::RoutingError do
  get '/example'
end
```

Comment: That doesn't test the exception handler.  I want to test that the redirect works.